# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400, How can I solve this error in React.js + Django App?

Tags: django, reactjs, redux, axios, react-hooks

I am programming an app with a Django rest API and React.js frontend installed in a django app.

I am encountering an error when trying to make a post request from react to the rest API.

Posting to the Django rest API works in postman.  I am trying to set up the component with the useState hook, Redux and axios.

Im not totally sure I set up the state correctly.

Here is the relevant code:
From the form component (I suspect the error is here):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { addLead } from "../../actions/leads";

const Form = ({ addLead }) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const lead = { name, email, message };

    addLead(lead);
    // Clear Fields
    setName("");
    setEmail("");
    setMessage("");
  };
  return (
    <div className="card card-body mt-4 mb-4">
      <h2>Add Lead</h2>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Name</label>
          <input
            className="form-control"
            type="text"
            name="name"
            onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
            value={name}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Email</label>
          <input
            className="form-control"
            type="email"
            name="email"
            onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            value={email}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Message</label>
          <textarea
            className="form-control"
            type="text"
            name="message"
            onChange={e => setMessage(e.target.value)}
            value={message}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <button type="submit" onClick={onSubmit} className="btn btn-primary">
            Submit
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

Form.propTypes = {
  addLead: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default connect(
  null,
  { addLead }
)(Form);
```

From actions/ leads:

```
// ADD LEAD
export const addLead = lead => dispatch => {
  try {
    axios.post("/api/leads/", lead).then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_LEAD,
        payload: res.data
      });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
```

From my reducer:

```
 case ADD_LEAD:
      return {
        ...state,
        leads: [...state.leads, action.payload]
      };
```

The servers are running without errors. The form is displaying and the onChange functions are working.  The onSubmit function in the Form.js above causes the issue. Here is the error:

```
VM348 xhr.js:172 POST http://localhost:8000/api/leads/ 400 (Bad Request)
dispatchXhrRequest @ VM348 xhr.js:172
xhrAdapter @ VM348 xhr.js:11
dispatchRequest @ VM342 dispatchRequest.js:59
Promise.then (async)
request @ VM339 Axios.js:53
Axios.<computed> @ VM339 Axios.js:78
wrap @ VM337 bind.js:9
eval @ VM333 leads.js:44
eval @ VM364 index.js:9
dispatch @ VM280:1
eval @ VM315 redux.js:483
onSubmit @ VM297 Form.js:46
callCallback @ VM290 react-dom.development.js:362
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ VM290 react-dom.development.js:411
invokeGuardedCallback @ VM290 react-dom.development.js:466
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ VM290 react-dom.development.js:480
executeDispatch @ VM290 react-dom.development.js:612
executeDispatchesInOrder @ VM290 react-dom.development.js:637
executeDispatchesAndRelease @ VM290 react-dom.development.js:743
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @ VM290 react-dom.development.js:752
forEachAccumulated @ VM290 react-dom.development.js:724
runEventsInBatch @ VM290 react-dom.development.js:769
runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch @ VM290 react-dom.development.js:914
handleTopLevel @ VM290 react-dom.development.js:5848
batchedEventUpdates$1 @ VM290 react-dom.development.js:24343
batchedEventUpdates @ VM290 react-dom.development.js:1463
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ VM290 react-dom.development.js:5943
attemptToDispatchEvent @ VM290 react-dom.development.js:6059
dispatchEvent @ VM290 react-dom.development.js:5963
unstable_runWithPriority @ VM292 scheduler.development.js:815
runWithPriority$2 @ VM290 react-dom.development.js:12188
discreteUpdates$1 @ VM290 react-dom.development.js:24359
discreteUpdates @ VM290 react-dom.development.js:1486
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ VM290 react-dom.development.js:5926
VM350 createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (VM350 createError.js:16)
    at settle (VM349 settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (VM348 xhr.js:59)
```

What could be causing this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked that the request data which you sent by using React is the same format as the request you sent by using Postman? About request header and the requestBody, try to make sure that the request on React does the same thing as the one you sent by Postman

Comment: This was the issue I had a few typos in my rest api endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In models.py in the leads app I changed the model to match the react post.  This is the working model:

```
class Lead(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
  message = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Once I changed this I just ran

```
python mangage.py makemigrations leads
```

&

```
python manage.py migrate
```

in my virtual environment terminal.

Issue solved.